# is there any css hack for firefox just like we use for Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

```
 <!--[if IE]>
// load script here
    <![endif]-->
```

this script i written inside this hack work only in IE. are their any hack to work with mozilla firefox.

Comment: Its bad enough that we have to know about this sort of stuff for IE. Do you really need to hack Firefox as well? What is it in FF that's badly supported enough for you to want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/06/28/css-hacks-for-different-versions-of-firefox/

or

http://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+css+hacks